# Why do some of my comfrey plants have leaves curling over?

Tags: leaves, comfrey

I noticed that the comfrey (planted last year) leaves down by the creek are big and flat, but the ones up the hill by the blueberry bushes (6 feet higher in elevation) are curled up (rolling over on themselves).

Why are the ones by the creek big, and flat, but the ones by my blueberry bushes curled up?

We have had an extremely wet summer so far this year.

Comment: Hi black thumb! Would you please post some pictures of your plants, including the comfreys and blueberries? Thanks!